# Select all where date is present of future only

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I know this code works:

```
$eventdate = new DateTime($event['date']);
$datenow = new DateTime();

if($eventdate->format('Y-m-d') < $datenow->format('Y-m-d')) ....
```

I need to do something similar in an SQL query.

Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE `date` = `$eventdate` or Future Date
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = "
    SELECT * 
    FROM MyTable 
    WHERE 
        `date` = '{$eventdate->format('Y-m-d')}' OR 
        `date` >= CURDATE()
";
```

or

```
$sql = "
    SELECT * 
    FROM MyTable 
    WHERE 
        `date` = '{$eventdate->format('Y-m-d')}' OR 
        `date` >= '{$datenow->format('Y-m-d')}'
";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE `date` >= `$eventdate`
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `table`
WHERE
  `date_field` >= NOW();
```

This should work as in this example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/225a3/2